# android: no such instance field

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get data thru AsyncTask with web service.
I have no idea why as I declared global variable 'arrayList1' and it has been initialized, but I'm getting error for the 'arrayList1' and it skipped doin the new AsyncTask.

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList arrayList1;
private ArrayList<List> mData;
private ListView mListView;
private ListViewAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mContext = getApplicationContext();
mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
mData = new ArrayList<List>();
mData = LoadListView();
}

public ArrayList<List> LoadListView(Void...params) {
    arrayList1 = new ArrayList();
    //here error occurred.
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<List>>() {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<List> doInBackground(Void...params) {
            arrayList1 = GetData(); 
            //GetData() is another function will return a arraylist from web service.
            return arrayList1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<List> arrayList) {
            mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(arrayList, mContext);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }.execute((Void[]) params); //error occurred skipped directly to here.

    return arrayList1;
}
```

Comment: You declared an ArrayList<List> , is that right? a list of lists?

Comment: yes, is ArrayList<List>, that was a mistake, but i had correct it, but the error still occurred.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using proGuard make sure to check minifyEnabled and shrinkResources in your gradle to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

No need to send void parameter.

```
.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are creating two different object's in one reference, try this code:

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<List> mData;
private ListView mListView;
private ListViewAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mData = new ArrayList<List>();
    LoadListView();
}

public void LoadListView(Void...params) {

    //here error occurred.
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<List>>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<List> doInBackground(Void...params) {
            mData.clear();
            mData.addAll(GetData());
            //GetData() is another function will return a arraylist from web service.
            return mData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<List> arrayList) {
            mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(arrayList, mContext);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }.execute((Void[]) params); //error occurred skipped directly to here.

}
```

Comment: Where you are getting this Error "No such instance field" ?

Comment: i saw the error at bottom panel when i debug.
i cant embed image unless i earned 10 reputation, but here is the link for the error image. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGyls.png

Comment: Edited my answer, plz check.